# Adding elements of list in scheme

Tags: scheme

How do I write a Scheme procedure that takes a list and a number as arguments and uses tail recursion to compute and return the sum of all of the numbers in the list starting
from the beginning until the first instance of the number m is encountered?
(If it is never encountered, the return value will be the sum of all elements
in the list.)
For example, (proc (list 1 2 3 4 5 6) 4) should return 6.
I worked the procedure and its basic case, which is if the list is empty, it returns 0. But then I need another base case, when the list does not contain the number given as argument so it returns the sum of the list elements.

Comment: then there is where I don't understand how the tail recursion is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is homework I won't be giving you a straight answer this time. Here's the general idea of what needs to be done, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (add-until lst num acc)
  (if (or <???>            ; if the list is null
          (= <???> <???>)) ; or the current element equals `num`
      acc                  ; then return the accumulator
      (add-until           ; else make a recursive call
       <???>               ; advance to the next element in list
       num                 ; pass along the same `num`
       (+ <???> <???>))))  ; update the accumulator with current element
```

A function call is said to be tail recursive if there is nothing to do after the function returns except return its value, as you can see in the above code the `else` part in the procedure ends with a call to `add-until` and there's nothing else left to do afterwards.

Usually, an *accumulator* is used to hold the partial result of the computation, and that's returned at the end in the base case of the recursion. In the example, the accumulator is called `acc` and at each iteration its value is updated, and at the end it's returned.

Of course, the accumulator needs to be initialized in an appropriate value. For the example in the question, this is how you'd call the `add-until` procedure:

```
(add-until '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 4 0)
=> 6
```

Alternatively, you could define two procedures - one helper that implements the actual iteration and receives the accumulator as a parameter (that's the one I'm outlining above) and the other, which receives only two parameters and always calls the helper procedure with an initial value of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Óscar López's answer is correct. Here is a version of the same code, using a named `let`, that is (in my opinion, at least) easier to read:

```
(define (add-until lst num)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (acc 0))
    (if (or ???
            (= ??? ???))
        acc
        (loop ??? (+ ??? ???)))))
```